# Macbook Pro not accepting media query using CSS

Tags: css

I have written this media query for Macbook Pro. It is not accepting the media query. My Macbook's resolution is 1280x800 13 inches

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 1280px) 
and (max-device-width : 800px) 
{   
.col-md-12.webtestingsocial
{
 margin-left: 29px !important;
}
}
```

Comment: any other suggestions how to write media queries for macbook pro 1200*800

Comment: Any one can help me this thanks in advance

Comment: Any one help me these please thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media Query for macbook 13 inches(1280*800)

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1281px)
{
 //write your styles here
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It should work this way:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1200px) {

   /* Your Styles */
 }
```

Also make sure you have this tag inside the HEAD

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: i have tried this but it is effecting in laptops as well

Comment: can you explain what is effecting?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ here is a list of media queries for a number of devices and sizes. Hope this will help :)

Comment: any luck with the link i provided?

Comment: @media screen and (min-width:1200px) i tried with this affecting for laptops as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128243/discussion-between-hunzaboy-and-user7047368).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because making your min-device-width value higher than your max-device-width makes it invalid.

Have you tried making the min-device-width 800px and max-device-width 1200px?